# Maximizar Frame

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy realizando un juego en java, pero cuando ejecuto los **Frames** me sale una pequeña ventana y le doy en maximizar y me maximiza, pero la idea es que salga de una vez del tamaño que es, edito en las propiedades del Frame y le maximizo el tamaño y no me da ¿hay alguna otra forma?

Los Frames los utilice con Layout null para poner las imágenes y desde ahí da el error ... Gracias si alguien sabe como maximizar el frame se lo agradecería mucho

Comment: Con el metodo Frame.pack(); haces que el gestor de colocacion actue y la ventana se adapta a los componentes que tenga y otra opcion para maximizar la ventana es Frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); con esto simplementa el Frame se mostrara en pantalla completa

Comment: Con frames te refieres obviamente a `java.awt.Frame` en vez de `javax.swing.JFrame` verdad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si es que quieres darle un tamaño fijo y no poder maximizar o minimizar el frame debes definirlo así en el constructor de tu frame:

```
setResizable(false); // no puedes maximizar/minimizar la ventana    
setBounds(100, 75, 1214, 637); // defines dimensiones(x,y,ancho,alto) del frame
```

Si es que quieres poner tu frame para que ocupe toda la pantalla y no poder redefinir el tamaño coloca esto en el constructor:

```
setSize( (int) pantalla.getWidth(), (int) pantalla.getHeight());
setLocation( (int) pantalla.getWidth() - getWidth(), 0 );
setResizable(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Para que el frame se muestre maximizado al verse tienes que definirlo de la siguiente forma:

```
nombreDelFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Comment: y obviamente hacer resizable() false